# Python: Using regex to find the last pair of occurence

Tags: python, regex

Attached is a [text file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vmjt1t3cgzn49ha/Output2.txt?dl=0) that I want to parse. I want to select the text in the last combination of the words' occurrence:

- **(1)** Item 7 Management Discussion Analysis
- **(2)** Item 8 Financial Statements

I would usually use `regex` as follow:

```
re.findall(r"Item(?:(?!Item).)*7(?:(?!Item|7).)*Management(?:(?!Item|7|Management).)*Analysis[\s\S]*Item(?:(?!Item).)*8(?:(?!Item|8).)*Financial(?:(?!Item|8|Financial).)*Statements",text, re.DOTALL)
```

You can see in the text file, the combination of Item 7 and Item 8 occurs often but if I find the last match (1) and last match (2), I increase by a lot the probability to grab the desired text.

The desired text in my text file starts with:

> "'This Item 7, Management's Discussion and
>   Analysis of Financial Condition and Results of Operations, and other
>   parts of this Form 10-K contain forward-looking statements, within the
>   meaning of the Private Securities Litigation Reform Act of 1995, that
>   involve risks and..... "

and ends with:

> "Item 8. 
>   Financial Statements and Supplementary Data"

How can I adapt my regex code to grab this last pair between Item 7 and Item 8?

UPDATE:

I also try to parse this [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tdpyvgsw01ac22z/Output2012.txt?dl=0) using the same items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code has been rewritten. It now works with both the original data file (Output2.txt) and the newly added data file (Output2012.txt).

```
import re

discussions = []
for input_file_name in ['Output2.txt', 'Output2012.txt']:
    with open(input_file_name) as f:
        doc = f.read()

    item7 = r"Item 7\.*\s*Management.s Discussion and Analysis of Financial Condition and Results of Operations"
    discussion_text = r"[\S\s]*"
    item8 = r"Item 8\.*\s*Financial Statements"

    discussion_pattern = item7 + discussion_text + item8
    results = re.findall(discussion_pattern, doc)

    # Some input files have table of contents and others don't 
    # just keep the last match
    discussion = results[len(results)-1]

    discussions.append((input_file_name, discussion))
```

The discussions variable contains the results for each of the data files.

---

This is the original solution. It does not work for the new file but does show the use of named groups.  I am not familiar with StackOverflow protocol here.  Should I delete this old code?

By using longer match strings, the number of matches can be reduced to just 2 for both item 7
 and item 8 - the table of contents and the actual section.

So search for the second occurence of item 7, and keep all text until item 8.  This code uses
 Python named groups.

```
import re

with open('Output2.txt') as f:
    doc = f.read()

item7 = r"Item 7\.*\s*Management.s Discussion and Analysis of Financial Condition and Results of Operations"
item8 = r"Item 8\.*\s*Financial Statements"

discussion_pattern = re.compile(
    r"(?P<item7>" + item7 + ")"
    r"([\S\s]*)"
    r"(?P<item7heading>" + item7 +")"
    r"(?P<discussion>[\S\s]*)"
    r"(?P<item8heading>" + item8 + ")"
)       

match = re.search(discussion_pattern, doc)
discussion = match.group('discussion')
```

Comment: Interesting. Works well. Now I have to understand what `re.compile` and `re.search` really does... but it definitely grabs what I want.

Comment: is this \.\ to capture the dot in `Item 7.`? Some of my .txt files don't have the `\.\` ... can I remove it?

Comment: \. is used to match the period.  The \s is used to match whitespace (including new lines).  Rather than remove the \., I suggest following it with a '*' (without the quote marks) so that it will match either zero or more periods.  If the \. is removed, the code will not work for files with the period.  I will edit the code to add the *.

Comment: thanks for the update. Your code works well with the first file I posted `output2.txt`, but I added a new file `output2012.txt` (see the bottom of my updated question) and for some reason your code does not work. I really don't see the difference between the files in terms of their structure... Your code should still work...

Comment: I looked at the new file Output2012.txt.  The second file does not have a Table of Contents like the first table.  I will change the code to work on both files.

Comment: Code has been written to support both Output2.txt and Output2012.txt.  Code now uses re.findall() and picks the last match.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65413/discussion-between-plug4-and-alan-riddle).

Comment: works fine! thanks. Actually, I like to catch multiple combinations of item 7 and item 8 pairs, and at the end I just keep the pair with the greater amount of words. That assures that I have the correct section.

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern with `s` option

```
.*(Item 7.*?Item 8)
```

result at capturing group #1
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/120)

```
.               # Any character except line break
*               # (zero or more)(greedy)
(               # Capturing Group (1)
  Item 7        # "Item 7"
  .             # Any character except line break
  *?            # (zero or more)(lazy)
  Item 8        # "Item 8"
)               # End of Capturing Group (1)
                # "  "
```

Answer (score 0):

```
re.findall(r"Item(?:(?!Item).)*7(?:(?!Item|7).)*Management(?:(?!Item|7|Management).)*Analysis[\s\S]*Item(?:(?!Item).)*8(?:(?!Item|8).)*Financial(?:(?!Item|8|Financial).)*Statements(?!.*?(?:Item(?:(?!Item).)*7)|(?:Item(?:(?!Item).)*8))",text, re.DOTALL)
```

Try this.Added a lookahead .